# Atualização de banco de dados MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou trabalhando com um banco de dados no localhost e o outro na produção. Em vários momentos preciso atualizar meu banco local para igualar ao do servidor.

Fiz um script .sh para poder copiar todos os arquivos da tabela do banco (/var/lib/mysql) e, assim, poder realizar o que desejo. Entretanto o processo é muito demorado devido ao tamanho dos arquivos das tabelas.

Quero saber de sugestões mais profissionais para fazer esta cópia. Na verdade, algo que eu conseguisse sincronizar somente as modificações.

P.S: Outros 5 desenvolvedores estão trabalhando da mesma forma, utilizando o banco do mesmo servidor.

Answer (score 4):

Então, o processo deveria ser inverso, e somente na estrutura das tabelas. O ideal seria utilizar algum sistema de migrations.

No entanto, para obter dados 'quentes' pra teste e afins num ambiente de desenvolvimento e/ou teste, acredito que o ideal seriam dumps contínuos (que vão ficando menos recorrentes com a evolução do software). O fluxo seria:

1. Alteração local no banco de dados: gera migration
2. Após backup, migration é executada no servidor de produção fazendo os devidos fixups
3. Após migration, mysqldump
4. Roda o dump no servidor local

Um mysqldump, mesmo na forma que você está trabalhando agora é bem mais 'leve':

Na produção:
`$ mysqldump -uuser -p databasename > dumpYYYYMMDD.sql`

Local:
`$ mysql -uuser -p databasenamelocal < dumpYYYYMMDD.sql`

Existem outras formas (muitas outras, eu diria) com programas específicos inclusive (MySQL Workbench, MySQLdiff) mas geralmente é algo simples e rápido e se tiver um banco de dados realmente gigante na produção, acredito que seja melhor só sincronizar a estrutura e criar um script de geração de dados aleatórios pra os devidos testes.