# Sincronizar sqlite com um banco de dados online

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite

preciso sincronizar(um jogando informação para o outro) um DB sqlite com algum DB de server como sqlserver ou mysql, e gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso, estou usando a linguagem C# com visual studio, Obrigado

Edit: Só para ser mais claro, estou criando um sistema de controle de caixa, e preciso jogar os dados do sqlite para algum BD de servidor como o MSSQL ou Mysql,
Porem não estou conseguindo achar solução, para usar webservice e afim. Obrigado

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como sincronizar um banco de dados offline com um online?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185521/como-sincronizar-um-banco-de-dados-offline-com-um-online)

Comment: [Sincronizar Banco de dados Local e Web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188495/5878) | [Como montar um WebService para sincronizar banco de dados SQLite do Android e MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81199/5878) | [Como sincronizar SQLite com MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59599/5878) | [Sicronizar o banco de dados do servidor com um localhost](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233688/5878) | [Sincronização de Banco de dados Mysql entre servidores (VPS)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225460/5878) | [Atualização de banco de dados MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21740/5878)

Comment: Se nenhuma dessas perguntas lhe ajudar, acredito que sua pergunta carece de edição com maiores detalhes;

Comment: Irei verificar todos, obrigado !!